# Reply from the telnet session gets divided into separate lines

Tags: tcl, expect

Currently facing an issue, which I fail to explain.

Using TCL Expect to send a command to a remote telnet device, which is running on linux(busybox). The command has a confirmation echo ending like

`'&& echo helloMyNameIsCarl'`.

When i'm trying to verify that the command has been send, the debug of TCL Expect's "expect" is giving me:

```
"helloMyNameI\n\n\nsCarl"
```

Same thing, triggered from another PC(not the destination device, but the source), is doing well - the reply is without the '\n\n...'. And the troublesome source device didn't have any issues until it's network adapter was replaced.

Example:

```
package require Expect

spawn telnet 192.168.1.1
set telnetId $spawn_id

exp_internal 1

puts $telnetId "get_linux_env_params_random_command && echo 11223344556677"
expect "11223344556677"; #verifying the command was fully sent to the device
expect "11223344556677"; #verifying the echo respond
```

And the debug of the expect will be:

```
expect: does "# get_linux_env_para " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "get_linux_env_params_random_command && echo 11223344556677"
? no
expect: does "# get_linux_env_params_random_command && echo 11" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "get_linux_env_params_random_command && echo 11223344556677"? no

expect: does "# get_linux_env_params_random_command && echo 11223344" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "get_linux_env_params_random_command && echo 11223344556677"? no

expect: does "# get_linux_env_params_random_command && echo 11223344\n\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "get_linux_env_params_random_command && echo 11223344556677"? no

expect: does "# get_linux_env_params_random_command && echo 11223344\n\n5\n5\n6677\n\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "get_linux_env_params_random_command && echo 11223344556677"? no
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. At least post your code.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Added an example

Comment: If there is a difference between sending machines, compare any file `~/.telnetrc` between the two. Look at `mode char` and `mode binary` telnet commands.

Comment: This one sounds interesting. Will check. Thanks